# What are the basics of CS i should know,before I start my journey into machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, books, learning-theory

I am myself a `non-cs graduate` and would love to be a `machine learning engineer`.

I have learned to code and know the basics of `Machine learning` as well. Now I would like to know what "`basics of CS`" I should learn to be completely job ready.

I sometimes have difficulties reading CS documentations and don't know how programs and computers work in background, I am also naiver on topics like *memory management, operating systems, networking, electronics stuff like microprocessor, compiler design etc*. Are these all necessary for my transition to AI? If they are, would you please recommend me a `short learning path or books or videos`. I hope I wouldn't need to go deep in these areas. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Computer science is a very broad subject area, and many of its sub-disciplines have little or no overlap with others. For example, knowing the basics of operating systems design, compiler design or microprocessor design are unlikely to help you make progress in machine learning (although each one is an interesting topic in its own right).

[Machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) is a sub-topic of [artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence), so the most closely related disciplines are other sub-topics of artificial intelligence such as [pattern recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition), [data mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining), [knowledge representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_representation_and_reasoning) and [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). Some knowledge of the theory of [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) and [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) would also be useful. Outside of computer science itself, you will also need some knowledge of mathematical topics such as probability, statistics and mathematical optimisation.

Comment: But I find myself having problems reading documentations,what can I do about it.Last day I was implementing image processing and I had no idea what I was doing.I just cloned a git repo went through the instructions they gave..but didnt understand a thing really

Comment: @RamShankerG I am not clear whether you actually *implemented* an image processing algorithm (i.e. wrote code yourself) or whether you only *installed* an application that someone else had written. In any case, you should be writing your own programs and learning from your mistakes. Wikipedia's article on [image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_processing) has a list of textbooks (under Further Reading) and useful links.

Comment: I installed an application somebody else wrote.But I still have trouble dealing with problems like memory issues,undeesratnding technical terms.For example I encountered sth like serializing of objects and also read about custom kernels in open-vino which I dont undertstand clearly..all these seems abstract.What can I do about it?

Comment: @RamShankerG It sounds like your underlying question is about study skils and self study methods. I was going to suggest you ask at [CS Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/), but I see you have already cross-posted your question there.